# Forming a list of dicts in a loop according to if conditions

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, key, key-value

I need your help.

I have this code:

```
import ipaddress
from ipaddress import IPv4Network
prefixes = []
ip_addresses_all = [{'address': '10.0.0.1/24', 'vrf': {'id': 31,'name': 'god_inet'},
                {'address': '10.0.0.10/24', 'vrf': {'id': 33, 'name': 'for_test'},
                {'address': '10.1.1.1/30', 'vrf': {'id': 8, 'name': 'ott_private_net'},
                {'address': '10.1.1.2/30', 'vrf': {'id': 11,'name': 'ott_public_net'},
                {'address': '10.10.0.129/30', 'vrf': None,},
                {'address': '10.10.0.130/30', 'vrf': None,},
                {'address': '10.10.0.137/30', 'vrf': None,},
                {'address': '10.10.0.138/30', 'vrf': None,}]
for ip in ip_addresses_all:
    prefix = str(ipaddress.ip_network(ip.address, False))
    mask_length = int(IPv4Network(prefix).prefixlen)
    description_interface = ip.address
    if ip.vrf:
       ip_vrf_name = ip.vrf.name
       ip_vrf_id = ip.vrf.id
       ip_vrf = ip.vrf
    else:
       ip_vrf_name = 'null'
       ip_vrf_id = 'null'
       ip_vrf = 'null'
    prefix_dict = {'prefix': prefix,
               'vrf': {'name': ip_vrf_name,
                       'id': ip_vrf_id},
               'prefix_description': [description_interface]}
    
if prefixes:
  for i in prefixes:
     if prefix != i['prefix']:
        prefixes.append(prefix_dict)
     elif i['prefix'] == prefix and i['vrf']['name'] == ip_vrf_name and description_interface not in i['prefix_description']:
        i['prefix_description'].append(description_interface)


else:
        prefixes.append(prefix_dict)

    
pprint(prefixes)
```

So, I wanna append the 'prefixes' list with dicts according to this logic : if prefix not in prefixes = [] - create new dict , if prefix with the same vrf already exists, then append a description string to a description key and update existing dict.

I struggle with this for 8 hours and it doesnt work, Ive got infinite loops=)

Intended output, something like that:

```
{'10.0.0.0/24': {'prefix_description': ['10.0.0.10/24'],'vrf': {'id': 31, 'name': 'god_inet'}},
 '10.0.0.0/24': {'prefix_description': ['10.0.0.10/24'],'vrf': {'id': 33, 'name': 'for_test'}},
 '10.1.1.0/30': {'prefix_description': ['10.1.1.2/30'],'vrf': {'id': 8, 'name': 'ott_private_net'}},
 '10.1.1.0/30': {'prefix_description': ['10.1.1.2/30'],'vrf': {'id': 11, 'name': 'ott_public_net'}},
 '10.10.0.128/30': {'prefix_description': ['10.10.0.129/30', 
 '10.10.0.130/30'],'vrf': {'id': 'null', 'name': 'null'}},
 '10.10.0.136/30': {'prefix_description': ['10.10.0.137/30', 
 '10.10.0.138/30'],'vrf': {'id': 'null', 'name': 'null'}}}
```

Or better in a list like that:

```
 [{'prefix': '10.0.0.0/24',
 'prefix_description': ['77-GOD-VPN-2  ----  Vlan40'],
 'vrf': {'id': 31, 'name': 'god_inet'}},
 {'prefix': '10.0.0.0/24',
'prefix_description': ['78-ELS-CORE  ----  Vlan142'],
'vrf': {'id': 33, 'name': 'for_test'}}]
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

make prefixes a dict and handle that code in the for loop

```
import ipaddress
from ipaddress import IPv4Network
prefixes = {}
ip_addresses_all = [{'address': '10.0.0.1/24', 'vrf': {'id': 31,'name': 'god_inet'}},
                {'address': '10.0.0.10/24', 'vrf': {'id': 33, 'name': 'for_test'}},
                {'address': '10.1.1.1/30', 'vrf': {'id': 8, 'name': 'ott_private_net'}},
                {'address': '10.1.1.2/30', 'vrf': {'id': 11,'name': 'ott_public_net'}},
                {'address': '10.10.0.129/30', 'vrf': None,},
                {'address': '10.10.0.130/30', 'vrf': None,},
                {'address': '10.10.0.137/30', 'vrf': None,},
                {'address': '10.10.0.138/30', 'vrf': None,}]
for ip in ip_addresses_all:
    prefix = str(ipaddress.ip_network(ip['address'], False))
    mask_length = int(IPv4Network(prefix).prefixlen)
    description_interface = ip['address']
    if ip['vrf']:
       ip_vrf_name = ip['vrf']['name']
       ip_vrf_id = ip['vrf']['id']
       ip_vrf = ip['vrf']
    else:
       ip_vrf_name = 'null'
       ip_vrf_id = 'null'
       ip_vrf = 'null'
    prefix_dict = {
               'vrf': {'name': ip_vrf_name,
                       'id': ip_vrf_id},
               'prefix_description': [description_interface]}
               
    if prefix in prefixes and \
            prefixes[prefix]['vrf']['name'] == ip_vrf_name and \
            description_interface not in prefixes[prefix]['prefix_description']:
        prefixes[prefix]['prefix_description'].append(description_interface)
    else:
        prefixes[prefix] = prefix_dict
        
from pprint import pprint
pprint(prefixes)
```

output

```
{'10.0.0.0/24': {'prefix_description': ['10.0.0.10/24'],
                 'vrf': {'id': 33, 'name': 'for_test'}},
 '10.1.1.0/30': {'prefix_description': ['10.1.1.2/30'],
                 'vrf': {'id': 11, 'name': 'ott_public_net'}},
 '10.10.0.128/30': {'prefix_description': ['10.10.0.129/30', '10.10.0.130/30'],
                    'vrf': {'id': 'null', 'name': 'null'}},
 '10.10.0.136/30': {'prefix_description': ['10.10.0.137/30', '10.10.0.138/30'],
                    'vrf': {'id': 'null', 'name': 'null'}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that method replaces one dict by another if prefix key is the same.

Comment: no, it doesn't. the last two `prefix_description` have two entries both

Comment: I mean there are two networks 10.0.0.0/24 and two 10.1.1.0/30 in different VRFs and your method doesnt allow us to get all the prefixes without replacement. There must be 6 prefixes in a dict.

Comment: it's still not clear. can you modify your question with expected output?